# How to Save Image from a URL in Local Photos album of Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, save-image

I have a problem with save image from URL in local photos album and My code:
But it shows an error at  mediaLibrary.SavePicture(string.Format("SavedPicture{0}.jpg", DateTime.Now), isolatedStorageFileStream);. Can I help you? Thank all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have checked the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO in your "capabilities" section of WMAppxmanifest.xml file. Provide some more error details, if this doesnt help you.

Comment: Thank you. I was fix it.